# How does memory usage compare on Droid X Froyo vs Gingerbread stock ROMs?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 2.3-gingerbread, motorola-droid-x, ram

If I upgrade my Droid X from Froyo 2.2 stock to Gingerbread 2.3 stock Motorola/Verizon ROM, is it known what the memory footprint impact is expected to be? (assuming I keep my installed app list and usage patterns identical)

For example, if my stock Froyo 2.2 ROM boots up with ~170MB memory free, and during my day to day use I end up with ~50-70MB memory free (this is with ALL my actively used apps loaded, and Android not killing any of them to make room for others), what would the expected memory footprint be on a stock Verizon OTA updated Gingerbread ROM?

Please note that the question is specific to MotoBlurry stock Droid X ROMs, though I would appreciate a good statistical comparisons of AOSP 2.2 vs 2.3 as well - but for the latter, I'm completely not interested in subjective one-person accounts, just large scale statistics.